# Teacher turns racist and violent classmates into peaceful individuals

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama

I have seen this american movie (english) in high school. My english teacher loved it so much that she decided to show it to the whole class.  Production date should be between 2002 and 2007.

It's about a teacher, a very nice selfless beautiful woman, who is passionate about teaching decided to teach in some school.

In the movie, I remember that she broke up with her fiance or she divorced because all her time was dedicated to her class.

The class was a disaster, it had gangs, guns, was full of racism, until the teacher came to the class and turned everything around.

I remember a girl who told her in class

> I hate you, I hate white people

At first, students were extremely rude to her. Then they started changing and learning from her.

The movie was touching, it had me tears, it pictured the teacher giving exercises to students which help them understand and love each other.

She asked each student to write painful experiences about their life and leave the writings in class, once they left, she sad one night and read all the painful experiences of each student.

I remember also she took them to a museum (probably something about Anne Frank and the holocaust).

Anyone identify it for me?

Comment: It reminds me a lot of Dangerous Minds from 1995 starring Michelle Pfeiffer, but I don't remember any holocaust museum.

Comment: @Dannie, nope. I just checked and it isn't this one.

Comment: Sounds like every sappy "teacher saviour" movie from the 80s/90s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Freedom Writers (2007)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0463998/) with Hilary Swank

They take a field trip to the [Museum of Tolerance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_of_Tolerance).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_Writers

Comment: Yep, that's it. Huge thanks, this movie got to be one of the best movies I have ever seen.